# Lambda expression - Arrays.sort method is called same thread or not?

Tags: java-8

I have the following question from the book "Java 8 for the impatients":

Is the comparator code in the Arrays.sort method called in the same thread as
the call to sort or a different thread?

```
Arrays.sort(words,
(first, second) -> Integer.compare(first.length(), second.length()));
```

I am not sure I understand this question correctly. Should it not be running the same thread? Why would the question of multi-threading arise?

Comment: Please read the question properly.

Comment: You answered the question yourself.

Answer (score 1):

You can just step through the code in question, e.g. via your IDE or grepcode:

http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/8u40-b25/java/util/Arrays.java#Arrays.sort%28java.lang.Object%5B%5D%2Cjava.util.Comparator%29

```
public static <T> void More ...sort(T[] a, Comparator<? super T> c) {
    if (c == null) {
        sort(a);
    } else {
        if (LegacyMergeSort.userRequested)
            legacyMergeSort(a, c);
        else
            TimSort.sort(a, 0, a.length, c, null, 0, 0);
    }
}
```

And from there -> http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/8u40-b25/java/util/TimSort.java#TimSort.sort%28java.lang.Object%5B%5D%2Cint%2Cint%2Cjava.util.Comparator%2Cjava.lang.Object%5B%5D%2Cint%2Cint%29

Which is all single-threaded, happening in the same thread.